# Azure Pipeline FTP File Patterns not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

Want to exclude xx.dll from ftp upload it is not working as expected.Let me know reason or correction looking for suggestion on this

```
steps:
- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xx'
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: inputs
    serverUrl: 'xx'
    username: xx
    password: xx
    rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xx'
    filePatterns: |
     !**/xx.dll
     **
    remoteDirectory: /
    cleanContents: true
    preservePaths: true
```

Comment: My guess would be that you should include `**` first, then exclude `!**/xx.dll` from that, so switch the order of the patterns around.

Comment: Let me try once and I will confirm you , thanks

Comment: No luck on this @jessehouwing

Comment: Can you add more details on what parts are working and which ones aren't?

Comment: I don't have much logic just ftp upload in release pipeline
steps:
- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xx-ASP.NET-CI_newprocess/publish'
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: inputs
    serverUrl: 'ftp://xx.xx'
    username: signagestaging
    password: Avrhil404
    rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xx-ASP.NET-CI_newprocess/publish'
    filePatterns: |
     **
     !**/DigitalSignage.dll
     
    remoteDirectory: /
    cleanContents: true
    preservePaths: true

Comment: 'steps:
- task: xx.updateconfig-task@1
  displayName: 'Update config variables'
  inputs:
    rootDirectory: '$(DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xx-ASP.NET/publish'
steps:
- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload: $(DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xx-ASP.NET/publish'
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: inputs
    serverUrl: 'ftp://xx.xx'
    username: xx
    password: xx
    rootDirectory: '$(DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xx-ASP.NET/publish'
    filePatterns: |
     **
     !**/DigitalSignage.dll    
    remoteDirectory: /
    cleanContents: true
    preservePaths: true'

Comment: And what behavior are you seeing, and what were you expecting.

Comment: I want to exclude digital signage.dll from uploading to ftp

Comment: Hi this issue got sorted out

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this after migration of project architecture to .net core from framework by using core build pipeline

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. As it’s written, your answer doesn’t give enough information that the average reader is going to understand how to use it to solve a similar problem. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details and to clarify your recommendation for the benefit of the community?** Regards.